# using a for loop inside an append argument

Tags: python, json, list

```
instrument = 'instrument_name'
serial_no = 'instrument_serialNo'

list1 = []  # this list has an unknown number of elements (readings)
number_elements = len(list1)
```

Here is more code that adds readings to the list provided they meet given requirements which leads to a list with unknown number of elements dat i want to dump onto a jason file

```
instrument_data = []

instrument_data.appent({

    'Instrument Name' : instrument,

    'Instrument Serial Number' : serial_no,

    for x in range(1, number_elemensts + 1):

        'reading {}'.format(x) : list1[x - 1]


})
```

I want to create a table that looks like.

```
instrument name | instrument serial number | reading 1| reading 2| reading 3 ...ect
```

Answer (score 0):

used update on dictionery, hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
instrument = 'instrument_name'
serial_no = 'instrument_serialNo'

list1 = [1,2,3]  # this list has an unknown number of elements (readings)
number_elements = len(list1)

instrument_data = {}
dict_={}
for x in range(1, number_elements + 1):
    dict_.update({'reading {}'.format(x):list1[x - 1]})

instrument_data.update({

    'Instrument Name' : instrument,

    'Instrument Serial Number' : serial_no,

})

instrument_data.update(dict_)

print(pd.DataFrame(instrument_data,index=[0]))
```

output:

```
   Instrument Name Instrument Serial Number  reading 1  reading 2  reading 3
0  instrument_name      instrument_serialNo          1          2          3
```